# Why do Stack Overflow formatting buttons sometimes disappear when writing on a mobile phone?

Tags: bug, android-app

When answering some questions or writing comments in the Stack Overflow Android app I've noticed that there are moments that I have no access to that special Stack Overflow keyboard (it simply disappears):

[image: Screenshot of Stack Overflow keyboard]

I haven't found any circumstances that have to be fulfilled to make these buttons show up again. Sometimes clicking "Back" button helps, and sometimes I need to click on some parts of my answer, then delete them and again buttons show up.

Am I the only one having this problem (due to having the Swift-key keyboard installed or due to my mobile phone configuration) or is this a problem with the code provided to create that additional keyboard in Android or even a problem of Android itself?

I thought it might be a common issue and wanted to get some information what is the reason of it, to avoid this problem when developing my own Android applications on the future.

Phone: Xiaomi Redmi 3s 
Android: 6.0.1 
MIUI: 8.5.4.0 Global

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/270/meaning-of-downvotes-in-meta-vs-main-sites. But I don't really understand the reason for the DV here. It's a bug; perhaps it's that you've not really given enough context to repro.

Comment: AFAIK, the formatting toolbar will only appear when the main keyboard is active and the cursor is on the question/answer box. There's no formatting toolbar for comment though.

Comment: Your comment seems to be 100% correct in the case of SwiftKey keyboard and in the case of toolbar not showing in the comments section.When changing it to GBoard though, toolbar doesn't disappear no matter if I have main keyboard or that containing symbols currently active. Do you think it might be some kind of a bug or is it ok that toolbar behaves different when using keyboards from different providers?

Comment: I encounter this bug all the time, it is really annoying. Sometimes, even though I'm typing in the edit box, the formatting toolbar is not visible.  I have to press Back to cancel editing, and then click on the edit box again, and then the toolbar appears. And yes, I do use SwiftKey as my primary keyboard.