# Can't find formatting buttons on any Stack Exchange websites

Tags: support, bug

So today suddenly, all the formatting buttons on question as well as answer pane on Stack Overflow suddenly disappeared for me. I don't know what changed.

By formatting buttons I mean

[image]

It looks like this for me now

[image]

Moreover, if you look closely I also don't see any preview of the answers that I am typing. Usually there is an option to toggle ***hide preview*** and ***show preview*** but that seems to be hidden for me. I tried on another stack exchange websites and found the same issue with mathematics as well as cross validated. Strangely enough, I can see those buttons on meta while posting this question.

I tried logging out and logging in again with no success. I tried clearing my cache as well. I am using Chrome browser and I tried with Safari but the result is still the same. I tried searching for any similar issue and found [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/360092/why-do-stack-overflow-formatting-buttons-sometimes-disappear-when-writing-on-a-m) post which is related to mobile and has no answer.

I don't know if it is helpful but I'm on

Chrome Version 74.0.3729.131 (Official Build) (64-bit)

MacOS Mojave 10.14.4